# How to update values of an entire column in a table with respect to values of a column in another table with foreign key : MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table named hours_worked which has two columns, employeeID(primary key) and worked_hours_for_a_month. I have another table salary, which has two columns with attributes employeeID(foreign key of hours_worked), salary. Now i want to update the salary attribute column with values from the hours_worked(worked_hours_of_a_month) * 150 by matching the employeeID from hours_worked and salary tables. I want to update the entire column in one strike. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
update salary s 
    left join hours_worked hw on hw.employeeID = s.employeeID 
set 
    s.salary = hw.worked_hours_for_a_month*150
```

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this SQL Query

```
UPDATE salary s
LEFT JOIN hours_worked hw ON
    hw.employeeID = s.employeeID
SET
    s.salary = hw.worked_hours_of_a_month * 150
```

Here's the reference for [How to update table's column value based on another table's column value](https://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwjcxvHI0ufKAhXHSY4KHaUzCUYQFgg6MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdba.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F21152%2Fhow-to-update-one-table-based-on-another-tables-values-on-the-fly&usg=AFQjCNFzkimk6ouYcNTs0s97Fh3rpoI5Lw&sig2=qa2kV8vJFRdeqDsqC6csVA)